# How to automate perl script in Delphi?

Tags: perl, delphi

Currently, I am working in a delphi application. I need to run perl script from the delphi application. To be more clear, manually we are executing the perl script in unix window. Now I need to automate the execution of that perl script from the application.

I tried using ShellExecute:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('C:\loaderperl.bat'), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
```

The window blinks for a second and closed. I don't know whether the script executed or not.

Hi, Thanks for all your answers and sorry for my late reply. Still I am struggling with this automation. Now I will explain the process clearly, at present I open the putty window, connect to the remote machine and execute the perl script. The perl script in turn calls an store procedure and updates the table. Now I want to do above explained process automatically by clicking a button. So when I click a button, it should call a function which connects to the remote machine and then executes the perl script. Am I clear to you??? Please help to solve this. I need this code in delphi

Comment: Is it native delphi or .NET? What do you mean by unix window?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to execute this locally or on a remote system, and if locally which environment (CygWin, MSys) or which shell (sh, bash, rxvt, ...) you want to use.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454501/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-program-in-delphi

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, mghie - JVNR seems to want to check if it ran as well, which I don't think that other SO question really addresses - and it's certainly not in the accepted answer.  Also, JVNR, I think you could edit the question title to be a bit clearer or help other people find the question - maybe mention "running" a Perl script, not "automate", and something about checking if it ran or not?

Comment: @David: I agree that there are many more aspects to a *complete* solution, and they are certainly worth discussing. However, unless the question is clear on what is needed and what isn't there isn't much we can do. The question as it stands is a duplicate IMO.

Comment: Hi JVNR.  Please remember you should upvote useful answers and accept the most useful for your question.  Just letting you know since you look new - you need to provide feedback on this site.  If the answers were useful it's also polite to let the users who posted know, either by commenting or at least by voting.  This question has at least two answers that look good enough to accept, and at least three worth upvoting.

Comment: Hi David, I dont know to vote up in this site. I have edited my question. Please check it and help me.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited in response to comments below.)

There are a couple of steps to this: first, actually run the script; second, check if it successfully ran (both that it managed to start a new process and that that process succeeded.)

*Part 1, running the script:*

To run the script from your Delphi app, use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the "`open`" verb should work (more details in flags below.)  You could execute the script itself if it's associated with your Perl executable, or run your Perl exe with the script as a command line argument.

[This article](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm) looks like a good starting point for using this API and its simpler cousin [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The `ShellExecute[Ex]` functions usually expect your application to run a message loop afterwards.  It's unlikely your application isn't, so long as after the user clicks the button to start this your app sits idle, but if it isn't going to for some reason you should pass the `SEE_MASK_NOASYNC` flag.  MSDN has lots of info.

*Part 2, checking if it executed successfully and succeeded in its task:*

To see if the script executed, you should get a process handle to the started process and, if there was a new process, check the exit code from that.  You should modify your script to return a non-zero code if its task fails.  (I'm not familiar with Perl so I can't specifically tell you how, but generally it's the return value from the "main" function or other first/startup function.)  You can do this by:

- Pass in the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag to `ShellExecuteEx`.  That will fill the `hProcess` member of the struct you pass in with a process handle, if it successfully started a process (if not, check `GetLastError` to find out why.)  If this is all you need to know (just if it started, nothing about if it worked) then you're done.
- Optional: wait for the process to end by using `WaitForSingleObject(YourParamStruct.hProcess, INFINITE)` (if you got a valid hProcess, of course)
- Call [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the exit code.  (Check for it returning `STILL_ACTIVE`, and if it is still running wait and try again.)  Normally, it should exit with `0` to indicate success.  You should modify your script so that if something goes wrong it returns non-zero.  You can make the codes as simple or complex as you want - eg, return `1` for any error, or make a number of codes broken up by the type of error.  (Avoid using `259`, because that's the value of `STILL_ACTIVE` - doing so might lead your Delphi code into an infinite loop, depending how it's coded, thinking it's still waiting to get an exit code because the Perl script is still running when it's not.)

Your Delphi app can then check this code to see if the Perl script worked or not and do something in response if it failed - log a message, tell the user, etc.

One other thing - you say you just want to know if the script executed or not and the above should provide that.  Given it's a Perl script and runs on the command line, one other thing you might want to do is get its output, either to scan for errors if you don't return an error code, or to log or show the user.  You can do this by running it via [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [capturing the output](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3361.asp).  From what you say this is probably overkill for what you're after, though!

Comment: I would always execute a shell and pass it the script name as a parameter, to allow for wildcards, input / output redirection and the like. The shebang line will make sure the perl interpreter is started.

Comment: Automate means human interruption should be nil. While clicking a button, the code should automatically execute the perl script. I tried using ShellExecute:

ShellExecute(Handle,'open',Pchar('C:\loaderperl.bat'),nil,nil,SW_SHOW) ;

The window blinks for a second and closed. I dont know whether the script executed or not. Could you please clear me in this?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, JVNR.  I've just edited this answer to hopefully answer how you can know if it executed or not (and if the script worked - it's quite possible for the script to run, but something to go wrong in it, which you probably want to know too.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your answers and sorry for my late reply. Still I am struggling with this automation. Now I will explain the process clearly, at present I open the putty window, connect to the remote machine and execute the perl script. The perl script in turn calls an store procedure and updates the table. 
  Now I want to do above explained process automatically by clicking a button. So when I click a button, it should call a function which connects to the remote machine and then executes the perl script. Am I clear to you??? Please help to solve this. I need this code in delphi.

Comment: This is a late reply to your late reply, JVNR - sorry for that too.  I've been overseas for a couple of months.  I think you're in effect asking a completely different question than what you appeared to ask here, so the answer would be completely different.  It would be best to ask as a new SO question, perhaps referring to this one and your comment to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Start rsh or whatever your unix windows is with the relevant arguments (perl interpreter + script location+name) using shellexecute?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call external program (perl interpreter to execute on local machine, ssh or smth like this to execute on remote machine). Here is procedure that calls external program and waits until it ends (if you don't need to wait until it ends, remove WaitForSingleObject or just call ShellExecute as other people suggested).

UPDATE: To see script output, try to use solution from [this article](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article%5F3361.asp)

```
function ExecAndWait(const FileName, Params: ShortString; const WinState: Word): boolean; export; 
var 
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo; 
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation; 
  CmdLine: ShortString; 
begin 
  { Put the name of file between quotes, due to spaces in names of files in system Win9x } 
  CmdLine := '"' + Filename + '" ' + Params; 
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(StartInfo), #0); 
  with StartInfo do 
  begin 
    cb := SizeOf(SUInfo); 
    dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; 
    wShowWindow := WinState; 
  end; 
  Result := CreateProcess(nil, PChar( String( CmdLine ) ), nil, nil, false, 
                          CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, 
                          PChar(ExtractFilePath(Filename)),StartInfo,ProcInfo);
  { Wait the finish of program } 
  if Result then 
  begin 
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); 
    { Free the Handles } 
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess); 
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread); 
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `ShellExecute()` a batch file you need to execute `cmd.exe` and pass the script as a parameter, like so:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe', '/C C:\loaderperl.bat', nil, SW_SHOW);
```

You can use output redirection to capture the script output in a file. If you want to see whether the script was executed successfully you can (for testing purposes) add `pause` to the end of it.