# why does cmd.exe in CreateProcess behaves different from DOS-prompt?

Tags: windows, delphi, batch-file, cmd, createprocess

I use [Altar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46207/altar)'s `GetDOSOutput()` (variant 1) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454501/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-program-in-delphi) to call dos-commands by a simple delphi program. However, existing DOS program's such as DiskPart cannot be found when called by by CreateProcess whereas they present no problem when called from the DOS-prompt (Windows server 2003 X64). What could be the cause of this?

commandline: `ListVolumes.bat'

ListVolumes.bat:

```
path
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe /s ListVolumes.scr
dir C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe
```

output through the program call:

```
I:\PartScan>path
PATH=C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;

I:\PartScan>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe /s ListVolumes.scr
'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I:\PartScan>dir C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe
 Volume in drive C is system
 Volume Serial Number is 351F-0221

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32

File Not Found
```

output when called from the DOS prompt (note the final dir command):

```
PATH=C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Borl
and\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;

I:\PartScan>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe /s ListVolumes.scr

Microsoft DiskPart version 5.2.3790.3959
Copyright (C) 1999-2001 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: ISOETES

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     F                       DVD-ROM         0 B  Healthy
  ...
  Volume 11    G                       DVD-ROM         0 B  Healthy

I:\PartScan>dir C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DiskPart.exe
 Volume in drive C is system
 Volume Serial Number is 351F-0221

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32

17-Feb-2007  08:17           263,680 diskpart.exe
               1 File(s)        263,680 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  33,111,334,912 bytes free
```

Comment: It would be great if we could stop calling console apps DOS programs. There is no DOS anymore.

Comment: Or rather, DOS does still exist, but most of what is called DOS really isn't.

Comment: The solution is simple, use the [Sysnative](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) folder instead of the system32 directory...

Comment: As I understand it, SysNative wasn't introduced before Vista. The target machine runs server 2003x64.

Comment: I believe there was a hotfix for 2003/XP, google it...

Comment: You must be getting different search results than I do...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I'm not so sure that will work out. Can be tricky.

Comment: [Not so hard to find](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/942589)? @DavidHeffernan, never had problems with SysNative...

Comment: @who It's fine for reading/writing files. I just remember have difficulties using it to escape the emulator.

Comment: Yes, prompted by your perseverance I searched further. At first I only found more statements that it wouldn't be possible in this version, by then I arrived at the same kb-page you have posted while I was away. Honour is due: it works as a charm. I cannot be tested through the CLI, as it seems, for then WOW64 is not involved. But calling cmd.exe as "C:\windows\Sysnative\cmd.exe" does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not shown code so we cannot diagnose this with 100% certainty. However, the likely cause is that your process is a 32 bit process running under the WOW64 emulator. When you create a `cmd` process under the emulator you get a 32 bit `cmd` process, also running under the emulator. You are comparing that with a 64 bit process. Do note that under the emulator, `system32` is redirected to `SysWOW64` by the file system redirector.

The way you deal with this is to create a 64 bit process. That's quite tricky to do for `cmd` when creating from inside the emulator. The easiest way to do so is to call `CreateProcess` from a 64 bit process.

Since you use Delphi 7 you may need to use a modern compiler to make a small 64 bit executable that will do the work for you. Call the small executable from your Delphi 7 program.

An alternative that may fit your needs is to use the `sysnative` alias to reach the 64 bit system directory from inside the emulator. That is described in the [file system redirector documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).

Comment: The code is copied and pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454501/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-program-in-delphi.

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed. The same program code compiled by XE2/64 works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: OK, but we don't see how you called it. So it's always useful to give an MCVE.

Comment: result := GetDOSoutput('test.bat'); --- if you can learn anything from this you could teach me a lot more, I think.