# Execute a jar with Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, jar, console

I want to know if there is some way to execute a jar console application by Delphi and give commands for it like a cmd.

Actually I have a java application that I don't have the source anymore and it's limited to only two commands by console, so I want to create a delphi application and it will have buttons instead console commands.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454501/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-program-in-delphi

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need to run the jar and it need to still opened to receive commands later anytime but this can't appear for the user

Comment: Use `CreateProcess`. You'll need to create a pipe for the standard input (and probably standard output). When you have commands to input, feed them into the stdin pipe. Then read the output from the stdout pipe.