# Decoding a image of a QR code with Delphi and a webcam

Tags: delphi, qr-code

So I am looking for a solution to read a QR code from delphi with a webcam.
I found this example project to capture the webcam's image and save it to a .bmp file : [linky](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/delphiwebcamcaptureexample)

So I have the image that I want to scan. Now I would like to know how to get its contents in string format in Delphi. So to read the QR code I found [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) which is exactly what I need. I just cant figure out how to use it with delphi.

I want to know if there is a way I can either implement the libraries ZBar supplies or somehow run ZBar and just receive the decoded text ?

ZBar has a command prompt example so I thought that it would be possible to run the command prompt, receive the results and just format the strings to find the code (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454501/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-program-in-delphi)). But that seems rather hacky and I am sure there must be a better way. I also could not get any of the answers to work.

I am using delphi 7 or xe3 if thats a factor.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: "I am using delphi 7 or xe3 if thats a factor." Those are majorly different, especially when it comes to enforced Unicode.

Comment: Should I stick with one ? I just mention it cause it may open up more possibilities. But it doesn't matter at all to me.

Comment: Well that's a third-party software, not a library for Delphi. You might be able to use it, but I'm sure there are better options.

Comment: A simple search for "Delphi QR Code" and the first result: http://www.debenu.com/open-source/delphizxingqrcode/

Comment: That one's for generating, here's one that can scan too: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/qr_codes_delphi.html Moral of the story is, use a search engine.

Comment: I searched extensively (which I tried to convey through linking the resources) and the article you linked the example does not scan it only generates a QR code.

Comment: Did you see my second comment?

Comment: Yeah after I posted mine.. Oops :)
Not to sound ungrateful but I visited all of those sites before. The TMS component seems to use the objective C port of ZBar which is meant for IPhone and not for scanning images after they have been taken.

Comment: Compile the code into a DLL, then call it

Comment: here's an [example](http://blog.freehand.com.ua/2013/03/zbar-reading-bar-codes-in-delphi.html)  and it uses XE3...

Comment: Whosrdaddy that looks to be exactly what I need. The pascal header conversion seems to be critical to the whole thing. I will test when i get home.

Comment: I am calling zbar_image_read('blabla.png') but it then throws an error : zbar_image_read not found in libzbar-0.dll I dont know what to do now.

Comment: Should I ask a new question or edit the original one? I just want a simple example of how to use that zbar library. I just cant figure it out.

Comment: I suspect that the header is a bit outdated, just try the example in the link I gave you, I does not use zbar_image_read.

Comment: I opened that example but its a console application and i need it in a win forms application. I tried to transfer the functions but the main read_image one writes its results to the console instead of returning the barcode string. I just need a function I can call with a path to the image as string which then returns the contents of the qr code as string.

Answer (score 0):

The famous ZXing library finally has been ported to Delphi, but it is for the modern Delphi versions like Delphi 10.4, because there are new features used like in-place filling of dynamic arrays. I tried to rewrite it for Delphi 6 and didn't manage that.

Here is the link: https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi

There is also an example for a webcam.